# Are columDefs and columns mutually exclusive?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to make a table from JSON data formatted as arrays. Within that table, the column titles are dynamic (they're week numbers) but the rendering function for a specific column isn't. So I wanted to use the `columns` options for the title and the `columnDefs` for the rendering function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var messagesDataRaw = {
    data: [
        ["03", "129", "129", "77.36%"],
        ["40", "172", "396", "10.32%"],
        ["41", "614", "180", "10.29%"],
        ["43", "155", "221", "9.30%"]
], 
    columns: [
        { title: 'team' },  
        { title: '32' }, 
        { title: '33' }, 
        { title: 'rate' }
    ]};
var messagesData = messagesDataRaw.data;
var messagesCol = messagesDataRaw.columns;

var renderExceptionFct = function(data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<a target=\"_blank\"  href=\"http://URL_TO_TEAM#EXCEPTION_' + data.trim() + '\">' + data + '</a>';
};

$('#messages_datatable').DataTable( {
    data: messagesData,
    columns: messagesCol,
    paging: false,
    ordering: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    columnDefs: [{
        target: 0,
        type: "display",
        render: renderExceptionFct
    }
]});
```

However, this doesn't work. I might resort to using only the `column` option but this would imply sending the render function every time and i'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both options `columns` and `columnDefs` can be used at the same time. See [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs#Conflict-resolution) for more details.

Problem with your code not working is that you've a typo in your initialization code, it should be [`columnDefs.targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) and not `columnDefs.target`, see below:

```
columnDefs: [{
    targets: 0,
    type: "display",
    render: renderExceptionFct
}
```